# Importing WP database from localhost using XAMPP to free-host

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have been creating a localhost wordpress site and now want to upload it to show it to the client. I've exported the database using phpMyAdmin and have uploaded all the files onto the host. When trying to import the database I get this error message.

```
Error

Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)

SQL query: Edit Edit

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

MySQL said: Documentation
 #1044 - Access denied for user 'id2550264_admin'@'%' to database      'bitnami_wordpress
```

I have tried Changing php.ini at C:\xampp\php\php.ini using another post on here but nothing has worked this far.

Comment: Did you also added a db user that has privileges to that database?

Comment: Why don't you use a good plugin like all in one migration. It is seamless with import and export from whatever server to another. No code and hassle.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL said: Documentation
 #1044 - Access denied for user 'id2550264_admin'@'%' to database      'bitnami_wordpress

Your MySQL user id2550264_admin does not have correct privileges to your database.
You need to assign id2550264_admin full admin permissions for your database.

Comment: How do i do this? On my host i dont have the user / priviledges section.